# How to use Sentry 2 in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I have a Personcontroller and a Festivalcontroller in my laravel4 application. The actions in those controllers can only be accessible by an administrator.

If my database only has a user with test@hotmail.com, that user can access the routes of those 2 controllers. If my database has no user with test@hotmail.com, but it has other users, those other users can't access the routes of those 2 controllers. And when my database has a user with test@hotmail.com, and has other users, everyone can access the routes of those 2 controllers.

I only want the user with email test@hotmail.com to access the routes of those controllers.

I installed Sentry2 by doing this:

In composer.json file require:

```
"cartalyst/sentry": "2.0.*"
```

Run

```
php composer.phar update
```

In app > config > app.php:

`'Cartalyst\Sentry\SentryServiceProvider',` => to the providers array

`'Sentry' => 'Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\Laravel\Sentry',` => to the aliases array

After the installation I made the SentrySeeder file:

```
<?php

class SentrySeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();
        DB::table('groups')->delete();
        DB::table('users_groups')->delete();

        Sentry::getUserProvider()->create(array(
            'email'       => 'test@hotmail.com',
            'password'    => "test",
            'activated'   => 1,
        ));

        $user  = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findByLogin('test@hotmail.com');
        $adminGroup = Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('Test');
        $user->addGroup($adminGroup);
    }
}
```

In my PersonController

```
class PersonController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        try
        {
            $user = Sentry::findUserByLogin('test@hotmail.com');

            if ($user)
            {
                $person = Person::with('user')->orderBy('person_id')->paginate(10);

                return View::make('persons.index')
                   ->with('person', $person);
            }
        }
        catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
        {
            echo 'User was not found.';
        }

    }
}
```

Login action in LoginController

```
public function login()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
        'user_email'    => 'required', 
        'user_password' => 'required'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
            ->withInput(Input::except('user_password'));
    } 
    else {
        $attempt = Auth::attempt([
            'user_email'    => $input['user_email'],
            'password'  => $input['user_password']
        ]);

        if ($attempt) {
            return Redirect::to('/home');
         } 
        else {
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }

    }
```

Store a user in database

```
public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        $rules = array(
            'user_email'      => 'required|unique:users|email',
            'user_username'      => 'required|unique:users',
        );
        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        if($validator->passes())
        {
            $password = $input['user_password'];
            $password = Hash::make($password);

            $location = new Location();

            $person = new Person();

            $user = new User();

            $person->person_firstname = $input['person_firstname'];
            $person->person_surname = $input['person_surname'];

            $user->user_username = $input['user_username'];
            $user->user_email = $input['user_email'];
            $user->user_password = $password;

            $location->save();

            $person->save();
            $user->location()->associate($location);
            $user->person()->associate($person);

            $user->save();

            Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created user!');
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }
        else {
            return Redirect::to('persons/create')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your seeder code the user test@hotmail.com was not created. How could it find that particular user?

Comment: Well I changed an existing Sentry to the test@hotmail.com email and to the password test, but that didn't work either. I'm just learning to use Sentry2. I had my existing database, after installing Sentry2 I didn't change anything in database, do I need to add a table or something?

Comment: Have you checked your database to see if any account with test@hotmail.com exists or not?

Comment: Both messages are 'User was not found.', which one are you getting?

Comment: "I had my existing database". You do realize that sentry uses its own database tables for users, dont you??

Comment: Yeah, I have an action in my PersonController where I create and store my users. I checked phpmyadmin and a user with test@hotmail.com is in my users table of my database.

Comment: As @aayushshrestha said, have you executed `artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry`?

Comment: It says [PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre  
  ady exists

Comment: Exactly. Dont use your existing 'users' table. delete that and then run Sentry's migration.

Comment: https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/installation/laravel-4#migrations
Sentry's doc is really helpful.

Comment: So I need to add my relations to other tables after I run artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry?

Comment: Yes. I would suggest using user_id as a key for other tables to relate to users table or a different relations table. Having said that, there is no harm in adding a new field on the table either.

Comment: Anyone of you guys know an alternative that is easier if you already have an existing database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to use your own users table and also use Sentry's. So you'll need to add related Sentry's columns to yours. It's easy:

1) Go to `vendor\cartalyst\sentry\src\migrations`.

2) Create one new migration for every file you see there, example:

```
php artisan migrate:make add_sentry_groups_table
```

3) Copy the `up()` and `down()` code (ONLY!) to your new migrations.

4) And, for the users migration, you'll have to do some changes:

- Instead of `Schema::create('users' ...` you do `Schema::table('users' ...`, to add more columns to your table.
- Delete all commands for columns that you alread have in your current users table, examples of lines you must delete:

  ```
  $table->increments('id'); 
  $table->timestamps();
  ```

5) Run a normal ´php artisan migrate´.

After that you should have the Sentry's tables ready to work.

**EDIT**

As you're not using the usual 'email' and 'password' columns, publish Sentry's configuration:

```
php artisan config:publish cartalyst/sentry
```

And alter

```
'login_attribute' => 'user_email',
```

Comment: These new created migrations has to be in app > database > migrations right? Can I use the same names as in the vendor\cartalyst\sentry\src\migrations folder

Comment: Yes, but if you use `php artisan migrate:make`, they will be already placed there.

Comment: migrations are done, I also updated my SentrySeeder and PersonController. I think i'm still missing something. I still get User was not found.

Comment: Can you see those users in your table?

Comment: Yeah I see test@hotmail.com in my table.. Is in the user_email field and the user_password field is hashed.

Comment: So I think I need to change 'email' and 'password' in SentrySeeder to 'user_email' and 'user_password'?

Comment: user_email? shouldn't it be just `email`?

Comment: Well my existing database had user_email.. But Sentry will apparently use email.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44799/discussion-between-antonio-carlos-ribeiro-and-gilko)